# POST variables with NSURLConnection aren't showing in PHP script

Tags: php, objective-c, ios5

I've been trying to learn how to make post requests from iOS all day and have finally given up.

Basically, when I try to send a variable to my PHP server over post, the application recieves a response from the php script but the post data doesn't come through.

Making the request from iOS:

```
    NSString *postString = @"test=abc&test2=def";
NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [postString UTF8String] length: [postString length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: @"http://url.com/script.php" ] ]; 

[ request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
[ request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[ request setHTTPBody: postData ];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];

NSLog(@"responseData: %@", content);
```

PHP Script:

```
print $_POST['test'];
print " "; //space

print $_POST['test2'];
print " "; //space

print_r($_POST);
```

The response that shows in the console from the debugger just contains

```
responseData: Array
(
)
```

which is just from the print_r();

EDIT:
I just tried this using a separate web server and it worked just fine. So I guess the question why now.

**Solved**
The URL that was being requested was being redirected with mod_rewrite, thus post data was getting lost.

Comment: `So I guess the question why now.` - In that case, you can close the question.

Comment: Well, posts work from like <form> but not from the app. So its still the same problem I had in the beginning.